# Firebase SnapShot.val() returns null when trying to access data in vuex

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-realtime-database, vuex

I'm Creating an Application where student, staff and non-teaching staff can access.

my Form Data looks like this:

```
formData: {
      name: "",
      email: "",
      password: "",
      select: null
    },
    options: ["Student", "Staff", "Non-Teaching Staff"],
```

Of course in Vuex store i can register user with:

```
registerUsers({}, payload) {
    firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(payload.email, payload.password)
      .then(res => {
        const userId = firebaseAuth.currentUser.uid;
        console.log(res)
        Notify.create({
          message: 'Regsitration Successful!.',
          color: 'primary',
          classes: 'quick'
        })
        //set student
        firebaseDb.ref(`users/'${userId}`).set({
          name: payload.name,
          email: payload.email,
          select: payload.select
        });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
        Notify.create({
          message: `${err.message}`,
          classes: 'quick',
          color: 'negative'
        })
      })
```

I can also loginUsers with:

```
loginUsers({}, payload) {
    firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(payload.email, payload.password)
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
        Notify.create({
          message: 'Success!',
          classes: 'quick',
          color: 'positive'
        })
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log();
        Notify.create({
          message: `${err.message}`,
          classes: 'quick',
          color: 'negative'
        })
      })
  },
```

The Probems comes from this :

```
handleAuthStateChange() {
    firebaseAuth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      if (user) {
        //set Student
        const studentId = firebaseAuth.currentUser.uid;
        console.log(studentId)
        firebaseDb.ref(`users/${studentId}`).once('value', snapshot => {
          console.log(snapshot.val())
        })
      }
    })
  },
```

The Snapshot.val() return null in the console.

What i'm i writing wrong please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that, by calling `` firebaseDb.ref(`users/'${userId}`).set({...}) `` you are creating your user under a node

```
users/'userId
```

with a single quote (`'`).

And you try to read the node

```
users/userId
```

which does not exists, if the assumption that you mistakenly added a single quote is right.

---

In addition note that you don't need to do

```
firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(payload.email, payload.password)
  .then(res => {
    const userId = firebaseAuth.currentUser.uid;
    //...
```

because `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` returns a [`UserCredential`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.html#usercredential). So you can do:

```
firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(payload.email, payload.password)
  .then(res => {
    const userId = res.user.uid;
    //...
```

and also that you can do:

```
handleAuthStateChange() {
    firebaseAuth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      if (user) {
        const studentId = user.uid;
        //......
```

Comment: The single quote was the problem, thank you so much